# Do the shortest paths in from a node in a graph to all others form a tree?

Tags: tree, graph-theory, shortest-path

Given a graph G with root node r, do the shortest paths from the root to all other vertices form a tree? In another words, if you take the shortest path from r to all other vertices and combine them, do you get a tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, almost.

A shortest paths tree is a tree rooted at a node v that traces out the shortest paths from v to each other node.

If you take shortest paths from a node v to each other node, it might not form a tree, but it will be always be a DAG. It won’t always be a tree if two or more different shortest paths exist from v to some node u. But in that case you can remove some of the edges to convert it into a tree.

Comment: so to summarize, if i find the shortest path from the root to vertex u and the shortest path from the root to vertex v and fusion the two paths that form a tree, it's right?

Comment: Not always. If there are two different shortest paths from r to u, and the shortest path from r to v passes through u, you could end up with a non-tree DAG. But it would be easy to convert that into a tree.